# PHP scraping problem with Google "I'm feeling lucky"

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape using Google "I'm Feeling Lucky" button.

For small query like 'iteminfo.ca' it works, because it redirects me to iteminfo.ca.

This is the query url:

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=iteminfo.ca&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky
```

But for the query like '061754020164 site:iteminfo.ca' it doesn't work :

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=061754020164+site%3Aiteminfo.ca&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky
```

Because it is not redirecting to http://www.iteminfo.ca/Product.aspx?id=1011972978 as it does when you use that query and hit 'I'm Feeling Lucky' on google homepage.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you can't get lucky always :D Like richardtallent suggets use google api. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the Google Search API rather than screen-scraping.

There's more information here, including PHP example code:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/

Comment: This answer is outdated. From the link above

"Note: The Google Web Search API was officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010. Per our deprecation policy it has operated for more than three years past its deprecation date. Its last day of operation will be September 29, 2014."

Answer (score 1):

You'll get lucky more often by using the new style URLs:

- http://www.google.com/webhp#q=google+using+instead+overflow&btnI redirects
- http://google.com/search?q=google+using+instead+overflow&btnI doesn't redirect